# Django - Have function inside of a view function automatically return a response to user if error?

Tags: python, django

So I have this post request below that gets a video upload then validates it. I'd ideally like `validate_video_upload()` to return a `400` response if the video is larger than the allowed size rather than raise a validation error, because I'd like to notify the user that the video is too large. How do I set it up so that if `validate_video_upload()` returns a Response, it'll just return the call with the status and message, if there's no response returned then it just proceeds normally?

View.py

```
def post(self, request):
    if 'video' in request.FILES.keys():
        vid = request.FILES.get('video')
        validate_video_upload(vid)
```

function.py

```
def validate_video_upload(file):
    if not is_valid_file_of_format(file._name, VALID_VIDEO_EXTENSIONS):
        raise ValidationError("Video file format is invalid")
    if file.size>2296000000:
        raise ValidationError("Maximum size allowed for a video is 287 mb")
```

Comment: (Disclaimer: I've written this library.) The exception handling library `django-safespace` has a middleware to do just this: capture exceptions wherever they're raised and return them as exceptions. https://github.com/valohai/django-safespace#usage

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to have the function validate_video_upload return a value that indicates whether the file upload was successful or not.  That way your view will know whether it should return a 400 response or not.

```
def validate_video_upload(file):
    if not is_valid_file_of_format(file._name, VALID_VIDEO_EXTENSIONS):
        return False
    if file.size>2296000000:
        return False
    return True
```

```
def post(self, request):
    if 'video' in request.FILES.keys():
        vid = request.FILES.get('video')
        valid_video = validate_video_upload(vid)
        if not valid_video:
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
        # functionality to upload a valid video here
```